# How to make sections in todo list

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uitableviewdiffabledatasource

I'm doing todo in Swift using diffable data source.

```
private var todos = [[ToDoItem]]() // my dataSource 
enum Section { // my sections 
    case unfulfilled
    case completed
}
```

By clicking on the knockout that is on the task, the task itself should move from the unfulfilled section to completed.

I was also told to use the method with two arrays.

That is, I have my usual datasource, where will todo get to, tell me how to make sure that I have a second branch that is responsible for the second section, or how to solve this problem in general.

An example of my old code:

```
func configureSnapshot() {
    var snapshot = Snapshot()
    
    if todos.isEmpty { return }
    if todos.count == 1 {
        if todos.first!.first!.isCompleted {
            snapshot.appendSections([.completed])
            snapshot.appendItems(todos.first!, toSection: .completed)
        } else {
            snapshot.appendSections([.unfulfilled])
            snapshot.appendItems(todos.first!, toSection: .unfulfilled)
        }
        
    } else if todos.count == 2 {
        snapshot.appendSections([.unfulfilled, .completed])
        snapshot.appendItems(todos.first!, toSection: .unfulfilled)
        snapshot.appendItems(todos[1], toSection: .completed)
    }
    
    dataSource?.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
}
```

[image]

I don't remember the number of their attempts anymore. There were enough of them to tell me to use two arrays.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  It's not clear from the question.  Whatever it is, using nested arrays seems a strange approach.  Two separate arrays would be much clearer.  (and the force unwrap will cause a crash when the array of incomplete tasks is empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
//backing data source
private var unfulfilledToDos = [ToDoItem]()
private var completedToDos = [ToDoItem]()

//To-do sections
enum ToDoSection: Int, CaseIterable {
    case unfulfilled
    case completed
}

/// call this when you want tableview/collectionview to reload data
func reloadData(shouldAnimate: Bool) {
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<ToDoSection, ToDoItem>()
    //if you have no data for that section, tableview/collectionview will create the section with 0 height - thereby rendering the section invisible
    //however, if you have content insets on that section, it will still create those content insets on a section that is not visible. if this doesn't work for your UX, then simply don't append that section below
    snapshot.appendSections(ToDoSection.allCases) 

    ToDoSection.allCases.forEach { eachSection in
        switch eachSection {
        case .unfulfilled:
            snapshot.appendItems(unfulfilledToDos, toSection: eachSection)
        case .completed:
            snapshot.appendItems(completedToDos, toSection: eachSection)
        }
    }

    dataSource?.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: shouldAnimate, completion: { [weak self] in
        //reload of data is completed
    })
}
```